# Shotwell not writing metadata tags to images

Tags: shotwell, metadata

I've checked the box in preference to save metadata to images, but it's not saving tags or titles to the jpg files.  Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing here: is the progress bar on the lower left of the window not appearing?  If it is appearing, are you waiting until it's completed to check the JPEG metadata?

Comment: It works just fine on my computer. Ubuntu 12.04. Which version are you using?